# getting error while uploading bitmap image to facebook using facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting this response while using

```
Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),selectedImageBitmap.get(0), uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
```

**Response:**

```
{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Permissions error}, isFromCache:false}
```

**My code is**

```
Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new StatusCallback() {                                                   
    @Override

 public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
  Request request 
 =Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),selectedImageBitmap.get(0), uploadPhotoRequestCallback);

     Bundle parameters = request.getParameters(); // <-- THIS IS IMPORTANT
    parameters.putString("message", "Your Caption Here");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
  }
```

Comment: And, what exactly is your question? Have you gathered the `publish_actions ` permission which is necessary to upload photos?

Comment: @tobi can you please specify, how to add that permission in that code?

Comment: You have to gather the permission upon login into your app. IMHO your posted code is not about the login...

Comment: OK, and? have you verified your access token that it really contains the permission via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/